# ormlite for android: design help and more

Tags: android, sqlite, dao, ormlite, transactionmanager

It's a few months that I started developing android application. I have worked for about two years with Spring framework and Hibernate. So, searching for an ORM tool for android I found the ormlite project. I found it very interesting and I decided to used it in my application.

All seems to work fine but I would ask to the experts some tips on developing android apps using ormlite in  efficient and (if possible) elegant manner!

Lets start from domain classes.

All domain classes implements a fake DomainObject interface:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "job")
public final class  Job implements DomainObject{

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName="_id")
    public Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(index=true)
    public Integer remoteDbid;

    @DatabaseField
    public Date downloadDate;

    @DatabaseField
    public Date assignedDate;
     .....
}
```

Then I have a generic Dao Interface

```
public interface GenericDao <T extends DomainObject> {
    T queryForId(Integer id);
    List<T> queryForAll();
    void save(T object);
    void merge(T object);   
    void delete(T object);
}
```

implemented by:

```
public class GenericDaoORM <T extends DomainObject> extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper implements GenericDao<T>{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = GenericDaoORM.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

    private final Class<T> type;
    protected Dao<T, Integer> dao = null;

    protected GenericDaoORM(final Context context, final Class<T> type) {
        super(context, FileConfig.DB_PATH, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.type = type;
        if (dao == null) {
            try {
                dao = getDao(type);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                if (LogConfig.ENABLE_ACRA){
                    ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
                }
                if (LogConfig.ERROR_LOGS_ENABLED){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't get DAO for "+type.getName(), e);
                }
            }
                }
    }

    @Override
    public T queryForId(final Integer id) {
        try {
            return dao.queryForId(id);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (LogConfig.ENABLE_ACRA){
                ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
            }
            if (LogConfig.ERROR_LOGS_ENABLED){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't get element with id "+id, e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> queryForAll() {
        try {
            return dao.queryForAll();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (LogConfig.ENABLE_ACRA){
                ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
            }
            if (LogConfig.ERROR_LOGS_ENABLED){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't get "+ type.getName() +" list", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void save(final T object) {
        try {
            dao.create(object);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (LogConfig.ENABLE_ACRA){
                ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
            }
            if (LogConfig.ERROR_LOGS_ENABLED){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't save "+ object.getClass().getName(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void merge(final T object) {
        try {
            dao.update(object);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (LogConfig.ENABLE_ACRA){
                ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
            }
            if (LogConfig.ERROR_LOGS_ENABLED){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't update "+ object.getClass().getName(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(final T object) {
        try {
            dao.delete(object);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (LogConfig.ENABLE_ACRA){
                ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
            }
            if (LogConfig.ERROR_LOGS_ENABLED){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't delete "+ object.getClass().getName(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase database, final ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, Job.class);                 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (LogConfig.ENABLE_ACRA){
                ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
            }
            if (LogConfig.ERROR_LOGS_ENABLED){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot create Tables", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase database, final ConnectionSource connectionSource, final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {
        onCreate(database, connectionSource);       
    }
}
```

Each domain object has it's own Dao Interface defining extra methods (just in case other methods are needed than those defined in GenericDao):

```
public interface JobDao extends GenericDao<Job>{
    Cursor getReceivedJobs();
        ... 
}
```

and the relative implementation:

```
public final class JobDaoORM extends GenericDaoORM<Job> implements JobDao {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = JobDaoORM.class.getSimpleName();

    public JobDaoORM(final Context context) {
            super(context, Job.class);
        }

    public Cursor getReceivedJobs() {
        try{
            final QueryBuilder<Job, Integer> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
            queryBuilder.orderBy("reportDate", false);
            queryBuilder.selectColumns(new String[]{"...", "...", ...});
            final Where<Job, Integer> where = queryBuilder.where();
            where.eq("executed", true);
            final PreparedQuery<Job> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
            final AndroidCompiledStatement compiledStatement =
                    (AndroidCompiledStatement)preparedQuery.compile(connectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(),StatementType.SELECT);
            return compiledStatement.getCursor();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (LogConfig.ENABLE_ACRA){
                ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
            }
            if (LogConfig.ERROR_LOGS_ENABLED){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getReceivedJobs()", e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So my questions are...

1)Are this kind of implementation of domain/dao performant or have I introduced redundant and not necessary code?

2)Is this a good way to work with ormlite?

3)It a good practice to keep instance of each dao in a class that extends Application, or is better to keep an an instance of the dao on each activity or keep elsewhere?

I have also tryed to handle transaction but with no success.. I got an exception says that the table is locked.. I've create a method inside GenericDao returning a new instance of TransactionManager:

```
public interface GenericDao <T extends DomainObject> {
    ....
    TransactionManager getTransactionManager();
}

public class GenericDaoORM <T extends DomainObject> extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper implements GenericDao<T>{
...
    @Override
    public TransactionManager getTransactionManager(){
        return new TransactionManager(getConnectionSource());
    }
}
```

But when I execute the code in transaction updating DB i got an exception...

Thank you for your response!

Marco

Comment: I would split out the last question about transactions into a different question dude.

Comment: In the other question about transactions, be sure to attach the exception you are getting including some of the stack trace.

Comment: I'm also looking for some generic DAO mechanism, and your suggestion is perfect except one thing, which is OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper is an helper class to manage DB, but you extend your GenericDaoORM class from OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper, which is not meaningful. Usually there should be single instance of OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper. Better if we can figure out a way to isolate OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper from DAO classes.

Comment: Thanks to @Gray I found the answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273675/how-to-extend-the-basedaoimpl-class-of-ormlite-on-android-to-extend-functionalit, Just use OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper separately and use daoClass attribute of DatabaseTable annotation. Thanks Gray for amazing ORM framework..