# Get class from bounded type

Tags: java

I'm learning java generics and I don't know the right way to accomplish this problem.

I have a Bean class:

```
public class Bean<C> {

    protected Dao<C, Integer> getDao(Context context)
    {
        Dao<C, Integer> dao;

        try {
            dao = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).getDao(); //HERE
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The method `getDao()` expects as argument a `Class<T>`. When I simply place the `C` type, it doesn't work (even with `C.class`).

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088087/java-and-generics

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with another parameter on my method:

```
protected Dao<C, Integer> getDao(Context context, Class<C> clazz)
{
    Dao<C, Integer> dao;

    try {
        dao = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).getDao(clazz);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the `Class<C>` should be a field of `Bean`.